# Azure logging storage limits

Tags: logging, storage, azure

With various logging options available to be saved to an Azure Storage blob - what are limitations one should lookout for?

Can I place all logging (per region) in a single Standard Storage Account?

I understand that it would vary on how many resources are in the region as well as the amount of activity being done both on the resource itself (Diagnostic Logs) as well as the operations within the resource (Azure Activity Logs), but i would like to know if there's any ballpark numbers one should lookout for.

Answer (score 0):

The only real limits on blob storage is a max size per storage account of 5TB and a limit of 1TB per page blob, so yes you could place all your logs in a single storage account assuming they won't reach that limit.

That said, the bigger question is what you plan on doing with those logs? If you are doing some sort of analytics or search of those logs then having them all in the same place could reduce the performance of that activity if you don't need all the data.